# Laravel - Generate route to the delete method through link

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I have a PostController in which I have all RESTful methods. I can generate route to delete method by defining method in `form` tag like below,

```
            <form action="{{route('post.destroy', [$post->id])}}" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
```

But I need to generate same route with link,

```
<a href="{{route_to_delete_method_with_post_id}}">Delete</a>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<a href="{{action ( 'route_to_delete_method_with_post_id', ['id' => $post ->id)}}">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an link, which triggers your Form Submission with JavaScript. You cant create an Link with "POST" instead of "GET" Method.

As Basic example without JQuery and proper separation of code, add this to your template.

Add an ID to you Form "myform"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitMyform()
  {
    document.myform.submit();
  }
</script>
```

And change your link to:

```
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Delete</a>
```

if you want to show only the link, use hidden form elements.